# Disable Intel AMT

Tags: bios, intel-amt

I was trying to enable NIC teaming on my system when I ran into an error stating that I was trying to add an AMT enabled device to the team, which was not supported. 
Intel AMT is not something that I have enabled or setup, so I sought to turn it off. However, there is no option in the BIOS and another method of using Ctrl+P at start-up would not work either.

To confirm that AMT was enabled on this card, I installed the "Intel Management and Security Status" application, which confirmed that AMT was enabled, but not configured.

My motherboard is GA-H97N-WIFI and the instruction manual is of no use.

Can anyone advice how I would disable Intel AMT?

Comment: Just curious - what NICs? Also is this intel's teaming implementation or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Chipset Intel H97 (GA-H97N-WIFI) don't support Intel AMT.